Basic question on the meaning of this 'integral' sign in the control diagram
The input signal is run through max and min values comparator, the values of min and max can be input by the user.

I would like to understand what is the result of this comparator? Is this a standard representation of a certain mathematical operator?
What happens to the output signal if the min and max values are equal to 0?
This comes from a power electronics device control diagram (WECC documentation).

It limits the corrective drive. It "lies" to the controller the error voltage is between bounds Vemin, Vemax. Why? It can in some cases be useful

to limit the max power consumption
to limit the rate how fast some integrating block cumulates corrective momentum, because it could otherwise cause a massive overshoot when the right value (error =0) is reached.

If you set the limits to zero the corrective control function is fully disabled. Without knowing the system nor its dynamics I cannot say which limits would be optimal. The designer hopefully has given some tuning guide.

That's not an integral sign. It's a graph of the transfer function of that block.

The input signal is run through max and min values comparator, the values of min and max can be input by the user.

It's not a comparator either.
                     |
                   2 +     ________________
                     |    /
                     |   /
                   1 +  /
                     | /
                     |/
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
-6     -4     -2    /|0     2      4      6
                   / |
                  /  + -1
                 /   |
                /    |
_______________/     + -2
                     |

Figure 1. Transfer function. Input on X-axis. Output on Y-axis.

In Figure 1, the block functions as a linear amplifier (or a unity gain buffer, perhaps) when the input is between -2.0 V and +2.0 V.
Inputs below -2.0 V result in the output being clamped at -2 V.
Inputs above +2.0 V result in the output being clamped at +2 V.


What happens to the output signal if the min and max values are equal to 0?

The output would be clamped at zero. There would be no "err" signal for the output (PID typically) to act upon.
This can be used to prevent "windup". Imagine you have set the temperature to 180°C but the heater is disconnected. A PID controller will integrate the error continuously and get "wound up" so that when you connect the heater it delivers 100% power for long after temperature has been reached. This could destroy product and equipment.
You might find it worth your while reading my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/346759/73158.
